# Left-finite subsets in totally ordered sets

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

Let $(S,\leq)$ be a totally ordered set. We say that $E\subseteq S$ is left-finite if, for every $x\in S$, the set $E\cap\{y\in S : y\leq x\}$ is finite. Every finite subset is for example left-finite. A less trivial example is the set of natural numbers inside the real ones: each real number has only finitely many natural numbers before it. Does every totally ordered set without a greatest element have an infinite left-finite subset?

It is easy to see that every left-finite subset $E$ of a totally ordered set $(S,\leq)$ is at most countable. The function $f:E\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ given by
\begin{equation}
f(e)=\#\bigl(E\cap\{y\in S: y\leq e\}\bigr)
\end{equation}
is indeed strictly increasing, hence one-to-one. This also shows that $E$ has a smallest element. The question can be therefore rephrased as follows: does every totally ordered set without a greatest element contain an increasing sequence without an upper bound?

Comment: If $S$ is countably infinite and has no maximum, let $S=\{s_n: n\in \Bbb N\}$. Let $f(1)=1.$ Recursively let $f(n+1)$ be the least (or any) $m$ such that $\forall x\in \{s_{n+1}\}\cup \{s_{f(j)}:j\le n\}\,(x<s_m)$. Then $\{s_{f(n): n\in \Bbb N}\}$ is infinite and left-finite in $S$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No: consider the first uncountable ordinal $\omega_1$. Any countably infinite subset $E$ of $\omega_1$ has an upper bound in $\omega_1$, so $E$ is not left-finite.

Comment: I had the feeling a counterexample was to be found in the realm of ordinal numbers, which, to be honest, I´m not very familiar with. I was anyway able to understand your answer, thanks!

Comment: .... and if $E$ is an uncountable subset of $\omega_1$ then $E$ isn't left-finite either (fairly obviously).............+1.